# My array is not fetching the correct value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on the cart where i will be having a main product page, and when users click the product, it will bring them to the respective product page. So, every product have their own page with the same class of button.

I'm currently working on the cart, when users clicked the button, it will add respective product into to localstorage and display it on the cart page. But when i clicked the button, it keep display the same value from the array.

***HTML***

ex1.html

```
    <div class="product-description">
      <h1>Rainbow</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="product-price">
      <span>RM 87.00</span>
      <a class="cart-btn" href="#">Add to cart</a>
    </div>
```

ex2.html

```
    <div class="product-description">
      <h1>Unicorn</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="product-price">
      <span>RM 79.00</span>
      <a class="cart-btn" href="#">Add to cart</a>
    </div>
```

ex3.html

```
    <div class="product-description">
      <h1>Strawberry</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="product-price">
      <span>RM 69.00</span>
      <a class="cart-btn" href="#">Add to cart</a>
    </div>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
    var addtocart = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-btn');
    
    
    var products = [
    {
        name: 'Rainbow',
        tag: "b1",
        price: 99,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Unicorn',
        tag: "b2",
        price: 89,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Strawberry',
        tag: "b3",
        price: 87,
        inCart: 0
    }
    ];
    
    
    for (var i=0; i < addtocart.length; i++) {
        addtocart[i].onclick = selectValue;
    }

    function selectValue() {
        cartNumbers(products[i]);
        totalCost(products[i])
        dtime(products[i]);
        ddate(products[i]);
    }
```

```
    function setItems(product) {
        let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsinCart');
        cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
        console.log("My cartItems are", cartItems);
        
        if (cartItems != null) {
            
            if(cartItems[product.tag] == undefined) {
                cartItems = {
                    ...cartItems,
                    [product.tag]: product
                }
            }
            cartItems[product.tag].inCart += 1;
        } else {
            product.inCart = 1;
            cartItems = {
            [product.tag]: product
            }
        }
    
        product.inCart = 1;
        localStorage.setItem("productsinCart", JSON.stringify
        (cartItems));
    }
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but how is `selectValue` supposed to know what `i` is?

Comment: Is it always displaying the data associated with last value available in addtocart array?

Comment: @Pritesh, it will keep displaying 'Unicorn' value whenever i clicked the button from different product.

Comment: Can you change your for loop to below:

for (let i=0; i < addtocart.length; i++) {
        addtocart[i].onclick = selectValue(i);
    }

Comment: Where is "unicorn"?

Comment: @Kayden let me know if my previous comment has helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**selectValue** function isn't in your loops scope and even if it was the value of **i**
changing would still cause problems.

Solution for the loop part:

```
 for (var i=0; i < addtocart.length; i++) {
    addtocart[i].onclick = selectValue(i);
}

function selectValue(i) {
    return function(){
      cartNumbers(products[i]);
      totalCost(products[i])
      dtime(products[i]);
      ddate(products[i]);
    }
}
```

In case those html codes are in different pages. You should remove the loop and change this on each product (Change the number on each product):

```
 <a class="cart-btn" onclick="selectValue(2)">Add to cart</a>
```

And change **selectValue** function to this:

```
function selectValue(i) {

  cartNumbers(products[i]);
  totalCost(products[i])
  dtime(products[i]);
  ddate(products[i]);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem yet, as whenever i clicked the addtocart button, it still fetching the second array instead of fetching to the correct array.

Comment: @Kayden are those htmls in different pages?

Comment: Yes, those html are in different page

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes there is a small mistake in your concept. My suggestion:

change your HTML to like this:

```
<div class="dummyContainerClass" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"> 
   <div class="product-description">
      <h1>Rainbow</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="product-price">
      <span>RM 87.00</span>
      <a class="cart-btn" href="#" onClick="addToCard(this)">Add to cart</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function addToCard(currentClickObj)
{
    let myContainerelement = findMyContainerelement(currentClickObj, "dummyContainerClass");
    //After this, you can traverse all containing child elements.
    //And you can be sure you reached the right product.
}

function findMyContainerelement(childElement, targetCssClass)
{
     let curElement = childElement; 
     while (curElement.className.indexOf(targetCssClass) == -1)
     {
         curElement = curElement.parent;
     }

     return curElement;
}
```